# I tried to run rasa shell i am getting ERROR asyncio Task exception was never retrieved future

Tags: python, data-science

I am trying to develop simple chatbot using rasa framework when i run rasa shell to interact with chatbot ,it showing this error:

```
ERROR    asyncio  - Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<RestInput.on_message_wrapper() done, defined at /home/oretes/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa/core/channels/channel.py:392> exception=ValueError('X.shape[1] = 256 should be equal to 128, the number of features at training time')>

ERROR    asyncio  - Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<RestInput.on_message_wrapper() done, defined at /home/oretes/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa/core/channels/channel.py:392> exception=ValueError('X.shape[1] = 256 should be equal to 128, the number of features at training time')>
```

I am trying to develop simple chatbot using rasa framework when i am running "rasa train" command is working correctly,after that i ran "rasa shell" to interact with chatbot,it is showing this error:ERROR Task exception was never retrieved future.

i am using rasa framework

I am trying to do normal conversation with chatbot that why i am running "rasa shell" command but when i say "hi" it showing error:ERROR Task exception was never retrieved future.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [rasa community forum](https://forum.rasa.com/t/error-this-event-loop-is-already-running/24017), you may need to install the following modules, it worked for me on Windows 10.

```
pipenv install google-auth==1.10.1 prompt-toolkit==2.0.10 questionary==1.4.0 SQLAlchemy==1.3.12 urllib3==1.25.7
```

or

```
pip install google-auth==1.10.1 prompt-toolkit==2.0.10 questionary==1.4.0 SQLAlchemy==1.3.12 urllib3==1.25.7
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the above issue just by downgrading the questionary dependency.

[image]

```
questionary==1.5.1
```